# Is this a memory leak? (C++ BSTRs)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a function like this:

```
bool Function (BSTR paramter1, BSTR parameter2)
{
    // My Code
}
```

which I am calling like this:

```
Function(SysAllocString(L"Example1"), SysAllocString(L"Example2"));
```

My understanding is that what I allocate with `SysAllocString` must be freed with `SysFreeString`.

`BSTR` seems to be a typedef under the hood of `typedef OLECHAR *BSTR;`

Since this is a pointer, I should be fine as long as I add

```
SysFreeString(parameter1);
SysFreeString(parameter2);
```

inside `Function`, and don't name the `BSTR`s.

Is all of my reasoning here correct, and as long as I add these two lines, I won't memory leak? I still have a lot to learn. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Yes, that's a leak.  Easy to find out for yourself, just run this code a billion times.  Consider _bstr_t or CComBSTR, wrappers that do it automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. But this is usually not the appropriate way to design your software. In general, the responsibility for freeing an object goes to the routine that allocated it, or some related routine. You should be able to call `Function` with parameters that don't need to be freed right away, or with parameters that are declared locally rather than allocated on the heap.

Comment: A good workaround is to make your own `SysAllocString` function that returns an instance of an object that calls `SysFreeString` on destruction.

Comment: That's what `auto_ptr` is for.

Comment: Yep, that's probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @Barmar Actually, `auto_ptr` is deprecated and can be dangerous because it loses its value upon copying. C++11 has introduced `unique_ptr` as a replacement.

Comment: `auto_ptr` can only delete on destruction, not call a custom function (unless that changed in C++11?), so `auto_ptr` would only work if you create an instance of a class with `new`, and have that class call `SysFreeString` on destruction. But if you do that, you might just as well return a value of that class rather than a pointer. C++11's `unique_ptr` could be useful, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have made the suggested changes, and I now feel a lot happier about the way it is designed. Thanks for all your help :)